# Link para ligação em números de telefone

Tags: php, formulário, link

Tenho um formulário onde várias informações do usuário são cadastradas, inclusive números de telefone e, depois de cadastrado, você pode visualizar o cadastro abrindo um formulário igual ao anterior com campos disable iguais aos campos preenchidos na hora do cadastro

Gostaria de transformar esse número em link para o usuário poder ligar pro número do formulário caso esteja em um dispositivo móvel e pensei que seria só eu colocar um `href` , mas como eu estou pegando essas informações do banco e jogando pra uma caixa de texto, não sei como transformar em link.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="telefone">Telefone:*</label>
  <div class="input-group phone">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span><input required type="phone" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Digite o seu telefone:" value="<?=$row['telefone'];?>" disabled>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fui tentar o href mesmo e ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me dar uma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Até dá pra linkar um `input` que está `disabled`. Porem o evento de cliquei não vai ter efeito, justamente pelo campo estar `disabled`. Acho que pra resolver isso Javascript vai bem.

Comment: Provavelmente seria o caso de trocar o input por um simples <a>, e estilizar como se fosse um campo, ou mesmo colocar o <a> no icone de telefone, em vez do texto. Depende do objetivo final. Se for realmente uma âncora, o <input> de fato nem seria o elemento correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você quer que o clique funcione em um `input`, e não em um `anchor`, sugiro criar um evento de click no seu input, através de javascript.

Adicione a propriedade onclick ao input:

```
onclick="window.open('tel:<?=$row['telefone'];?>');";
```

Ficaria assim:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="telefone">Telefone:*</label>
    <div class="input-group phone">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span><input required type="phone" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Digite o seu telefone:" value="<?=$row['telefone'];?>" disabled onclick="window.open('tel:<?=$row['telefone'];?>');">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem, obrigada. obs: É o Jaskier nessa sua foto?

Comment: Por nada! Não, é o Dandelion do The Witcher =) (Edit: Não li os livros ainda, fiquei sabendo que é chamado de Jaskier, então sim hehe)

Answer (score 7):

É só você printar o valor no href da tag A.

Por exemplo:

```
 <a href="tel:<?=$row['telefone'];?>"><?=$row['telefone'];?></a>
```

Talvez você precise remover os caracteres especiais do href, caso não funcione em algum browser específico.
Para isso, você pode usar:

```
 <a href="tel:<?=preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $row['telefone']);?>"><?=$row['telefone'];?></a>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode tentar:

```
<a href="tel:55-5555-12345">(55) 5555-12345</a>
```

Comment: Então, eu poderia fazer assim se fosse um número fixo, como de um rodapé. Mas no caso eu to pegando esse número de uma tabela no meu banco de dados,

Comment: @MarianaFerreira você vai precisar normalizar.